# In App Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) is stated in section that "Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or  goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected."

Looking also into [iOS Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_standard_agreement_20110215.pdf) referenced in 11.12 of the App Store Review Guidelines I can see there in Attachment 2, section 1. 1.11 that  "You may not use the In  App Purchase API to offer goods or services to be used outside of Your  Application."

1/According to my  understanding everything which is not consumed within the application like  ordering of e.g. paper books, food delivery, flight tickets, electronics cannot  be done via the In App Purchase mechanism. Everything which is consumed within  the application like e-books, video streams, audio streams, new game levels,  etc. (when the provided content is in accordance with App Store Review  Guidelines and iOS Developer Program License Agreement) and user is charged for  this content, the IAP must be used or can be an option to other payment system  as stated in 11.3.

2/ For the In App  Purchase there is not any limit for the 30% fee for the Apple, e.g. theoretically if the content is charged for 10.000USD, Apple takes 3.000USD.

Are my assumptions correct?

BR
STeN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Note however, that if you use an alternative payment mechanism, Apple still wants their 30% cut.

Comment: Really? As I understand the 11.13 it says: "Apps can read or play approved content (magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video) that is sold outside of the app, for which Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues, provided that the same content is also offered in the app using IAP at the same price or less than it is offered outside the app. This applies to both purchased content and subscriptions." This looks, that Apple does not get the 30%...

Comment: @STen what are alternate payment mechanism other than IAP?

Comment: Hi, those are own payment methods. I.e. 1) IAP is not available in all countries 2) With your own payment you are not charged I guess by 30% by Apple 3) In some environments like ferries, aircrafts, etc. is not available Internet connection or is very expensive, but there is a local WiFi server, which can do the payment with use of your credit card or some vouchers...

Comment: Sorry my statement was very brief and vague. What I meant was that if you use some other payment mechanism, you still have to give Apple a chance for their 30% cut (i.e., via their system).

Comment: Apple doesn't take 30% over physical goods, hence if you use a voucher for buying a drink, you don't actually pay 30% more.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, it seems like your assumptions are correct.

Quoting from Apple's Guidelines - 
11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected.

This is validated by apps that are already in the Apple app store, such as Groupon, Fandango, Chegg and others that charge users credit cards for physical goods or goods consumed outside of the app without passing the transaction through Apple.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your interpretation is correct. Although in-app purchases have to be set at price poitns as well, you can't simply enter an amount.

Answer (score 2):

Apple does **not** take 30% of the transaction if its for physical good.

As stated above for such goods the app needs to use other mechanism then Apple's IAP for taking the money.
This answer is verified with apps and companies that I work with.

Other libraries for physical payments for iOS can be:
Card IO, [PayPal](http://www.paypal.com), [ZooZ](http://zooz.com) and maybe others.