# Possibilities for physical goods and services purchase on Apple and Android

Tags: iphone, android, in-app-purchase, paypal, in-app-billing

What are the best ways to purchase various physical goods, delivery and printing services, tickets, etc. on iPhone and Android platform? Since, both Apple In-app purchase and Android In-app billing are limited to digital content purchase consumed within the application, what 3rd party possibilities we have and what are your experience?

1. Premium SMS (Disadvantage: price limitations, MNO shares about 40-50% or more)
2. PayPal API (Disadvantage: not everybody is using that)
3. redirection to payment (credit) card gateway (e.g. [3D Secure](http://www.advansys.com/default.asp/p=87/3D_Secure)) *- added later*

Anything else?

Thanks 
STeN

---

**Added later:**
*For more information see also this: [In App Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210065/in-app-purchase)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've personally really enjoyed using [Square](https://squareup.com/).

Comment: Is that world wide available? Any advantages over the PayPal? Is your app on any market - if yes, can u give me a link, I would like to try it out. Please include more information.

Comment: Read the website, it's all there.

Comment: @Sneakyness: Don't know whether it answers the OP's query or not, but thanks for the link. +1.

Comment: @Mudassir To be honest I'm not entirely sure exactly what he's asking for. I've used Square as a method of accepting payment on some of the contract work I did back in Michigan for a large auto supplier. At the time, our payments totalled up to 1% of Square's total business! They put a hold on it, but response was quick. Can't argue with their 2.75% flat rate.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for ways to pay for the services and goods, which cannot be covered by Apple and Google in-app payment services... Teh problem is that premium SMS has limit to ~1.5EUR and 50% is taken by MNO, while the number of PayPal users is not that big to expect that most of smartphone users in Cenral Europe has account.

Comment: Have you thought about using bitcoins?