# Are we forced to used in-app purchase for international calling services?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We sell minutes to call other countries, and we want to allow users to make payments within the app. These minutes have a cost to us from wholesalers. Using in-app purchase will dramatically increase the cost to the user if Apple takes a 30% cut.

1 - "You must deliver a digital good or service within your application. Do not use In-App Purchase to sell real-world goods and services." (Source)

I'm not sure if this applies to me or not. Can anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210065/in-app-purchase?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Apple can give you a definitive answer, but the way I would interpret the paragraph quoted below, you have to use IAP for purchasing credits, and you also have to be able to use those credits directly within the app (i.e. make phone calls):

> Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume those credits within the application

Comment: i am accepting this answer because i realize now that you are correct. and only apple can give me a definitive answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Section 11.2 of [the App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) says this:

> Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

If the minutes you are selling are consumed by an iOS app (any app, not just the app in which the user buys the minutes), then this rule applies to you.

If you are selling minutes that are added to a calling card that the user physically possesses, then you *might* be able to bypass Apple's IAP, but you'll have to either submit your app or talk to someone on the review team to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

What you're selling is a digital service - connectivity. Your IAP product is similar to credits in most games in available on the store.

The real-world goods and services they prohibit are things like you'd carry out of a store in a shopping bag, or having somebody carry that shopping bag. They don't allow the sale of tangible things, only electronic. Goods for sale should be transferrable between two different devices.

I don't think you can avoid in-app-purchase for what you're trying to deliver from inside the app.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would carry a real world service out of a store with a shopping bag?

Comment: @koray “having somebody carry that shopping bag” is a real world service.  A more realistic example is a haircut.  You could (I believe) write an app that lets you buy a haircut, using your own payment system, and not use Apple's IAP.  In fact, you're not allowed to use Apple's IAP for such things.

Answer (score 0):

I think your case is much like Skype iOS app. You will need to go through in-app purchase for your app as the credit will be used to make calls via app to other countries.