# Billdesk payment gateway integration for iOS

Tags: ios, payment-gateway

Have done some exploration on available payment gateway APIs for iOS and came across 3 whose names cropped up quite a lot:

1) PayPal

2) Stripe

3) Braintree

But my requirement is **Billdesk Payment Gateway integration** in an iOS app. After doing quite a lot of googling and reading blogs, I still have no evidence of Billdesk being used in mobile apps. In fact, even for desktops could find only a couple of links describing how Billdesk payment gateway can be integrated with desktop apps.

So my questions are, can Billdesk payment gateway be integrated with iOS apps? If so, can anyone please provide the appropriate info, links?

And if so does Billdesk have a mobile optimized payment gateway or iOS compatible API? And is the web services same in that case(Payment request format and response format)?

Sorry for so many questions, but am unable to find a definitive answer so far.

Comment: you got the answer? i too waiting for the samething...?

Comment: Hi Suresh.. Billdesk Payment gateway integration with mobile/iOS apps is definitely possible, but you will not get much help/info by googling, on the open internet... Visit the Billdesk official site and contact them.. They will provide the required info..

Comment: Thanks Karthik, Is it approve by apple?..

Comment: It should be since it's only another payment gateway. But then again it depends on the type of products you will be selling.. If what you are selling has value only inside the app you can use Apple's IAP(In-App Purchases).. There are tons of topics that have discussed this like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210065/in-app-purchase ...

Comment: @Karthik: did you find any solution. I want to integrate Billdesk